# Structure of Measurable Subsets of the Unit Square

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

If A is a (Lebesgue-)measurable subset of the unit square that has positive measure, does there exist a subset B contained in A that has a product structure (is the product of two subsets of the real line) and that has positive measure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a measurable subset $S$ of $I = [0,1]$ with positive measure.  Then
$A = \{(x,y) \in I^2: x - y \in S\}$ has positive measure.  Suppose  $B_1$ and $B_2$ have positive measure.  Then it is well-known that $B_1 - B_2 = \{ x -  y:\ x \in B_1,\ y \in B_2 \}$ contains an interval of positive length.  So if $S$ contains no such interval, 
$B_1 \times B_2$ can't be a subset of $A$.